# Loop of promises. How to detect which promise returns the result now?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I think it's a common question, but for concreteness the situation is:
I use the [mammoth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth) module to convert `docx` files to `html`. The module returns a `promise`.
I have an array of files and when I use a loop to create a promise for every file I need to know what promise returns me a result (to know what file was processed).

```
for(var i=0;i<filesPaths.length;i++){
    mammoth.convertToHtml( {path: filesPaths[i]} )
        .then(function(result){
            filesHtml.push(result.value);
            //here I need to know the value of filesPaths[i]
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the question, the answer became obvious (as is often the case :) ).
You can wrap the promise with a self invoked function and store any related info in local variable.

```
for(var i=0;i<filesPaths.length;i++){
   (function(){
     var fileName = filesPaths[i]; //or any other information related to promise
     mammoth.convertToHtml( {path: filesPaths[i]} )
        .then(function(result){
            filesHtml.push({
                text:result.value,
                fileName:fileName
                         });

        })
    })()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use .map() array method (which is much like your solution in terms of function calls, but a bit cleaner):

```
filesPaths.map(function(fileName, i){
  mammoth.convertToHtml({path: fileName})
    .then(/* ... */)
  ;
});
// Here filesHtml is empty and you don't know when will be filled!!
```

...which is dirty (see the comment at the end).

Or you can simply use Promise.all() to collect the results:

```
var P = Promise.all(
  filesPaths.map(function(fileName){
    return mammoth.convertToHtml({path: fileName});
  })
).then(function(resultArr){
  return Promise.all(resultArr.map(function(result, i){
    return {
      text: text.value,
      fileName: filesPaths[i],
    };
  }));
}).then(function(filesHtml){
  /* Here you know filesHtml is fully filled */
});

P.then(function(filesHtml){
  /* ...and here too */
});
```

This way, you also aren't messing things with global (or higher scope) variables.

Comment: Your first solution is really cleaner. And I think that it's better (cleaner) to use `.forEach()` then `.map()`. Regarding your comment that I don't know when all promises are processed - I use counter for this. Regarding `Promise.all` it's not good in this case, since `If any of the passed in promises rejects, the all Promise immediately rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, discarding all the other promises whether or not they have resolved.` so if the module cannot convert one of the files, all the files will not be converted.

Comment: I would'nt mean you can check. Obviously you can loop (using a timeout or other async approach because, otherwise, there is no chance to the other async work to be processed). I simply mean that this is not immediate and you should handle it by hand. About the rejections it is trivial to switch them to a resolved promise with some error code as value or simbly discard it.

Comment: …the only real drawback of that approach (which I ommitted in the sake of brevity) is that, that way, if you need to be some hard processing with the result, you are waiting to all files being converted before to start that, otherwise, could be done asynchronously while the rest of files are being converted. But it doesn't seem to be your case…

Comment: Sorry. In my first comment, I would say "I would'nt mean you CAN'T". Sorry. And I can't edit it now…

Comment: You say: ** About the rejections it is trivial to switch them to a resolved promise with some error code as value or simbly discard it.**  The problem that it's external module.

Comment: It doesn't matter: `P.catch(Promise.resolve).then(…)`

Answer (score 0):

To respond to your own answer with an alternative:

Creating functions in loops is not a great idea, it's a pretty good way to an unknown number of functions created. If you used a forEach loop you would get the same encapsulation in its callback function.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function prom(thing) {
    return Promise.resolve(thing);
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    prom(arr[i]).then(function(val){ 
        console.log(`for: got val ${val} with arr[${i}]`);
    });
}   
// Logs:
// "for: got val a with arr[3]"
// "for: got val b with arr[3]"
// "for: got val c with arr[3]"

arr.forEach(function(val, index) {
    prom(val).then(function(val){ 
        console.log(`forEach: got val ${val} with arr[${index}]`);
    });      
});
// Logs:
// "forEach: got val a with arr[0]"
// "forEach: got val b with arr[1]"
// "forEach: got val c with arr[2]"
```